# Bind data with PDOStatement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help me, I can't using bindValue() in PDOStatement.

```
        $statement = self::$dbConn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM :tableDB WHERE id = :id");
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindValue(":tableDB", $tableDB, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

When i run this script.

```
        $statement = self::$dbConn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM :tableDB WHERE id = :id");
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // Return true
        $statement->bindValue(":tableDB", $tableDB, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Return true
```

But when run to:

```
$statement->execute(); // Return false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding table name.  You cannot do that.

Use the table name directly in the query as follows:

```
$statement = self::$dbConn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM table_name WHERE id = :id");
$statement->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// $statement->bindValue(":tableDB", $tableDB, PDO::PARAM_STR); <-- Remove this line
```

Update: Replaced query to use table name instead of variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have remove this. But it show error:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
... Pls help :(

Comment: Ok Thanks you. 
I miss syntax 

    $statement = self::$dbConn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM $tableDB WHERE id = :id");

I replace = : to =: :)

Thanks!

Comment: Using the table name directly in the query is dangerous and error prone.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, using a variable might be but not table name.

Comment: Correct yourself, not me. I just used the exact wording of yours.